# Posterior predictive distribution of ratio of rate parameters of Poisson random variables?

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, poisson-distribution, posterior

I'm working with a series of Poisson processes and I'm interested in estimating the ratio of the number of events related to these processes. I thought about drawing posterior predictive samples from each process and then take the ratio of the event counts; but the base rates are low, so there may be many zeros in both predicted series.

Is there a way to predict the posterior predictive ratio directly from the ratio of the Poisson posteriors?

EDIT:

To put more context. I'm evaluating the impact of COVID of the number of new diagnosis in our hospital for a certain subtype of a disease over the total for the disease, with the following random effects model: `Cases ~ Diagnosis * Gender * Age.gt14 + (Diagnosis * Gender * Age.gt14 | Period/Year), offset = log(Days)`, with Period being subdivision of the year based on the lockdown in the middle of it, and Diagnosis marking if the patient had or not the subtype of interest.

Then I would predict the expected number of cases for various combinations of patient characteristics with and without the disease subtype and get subtype incidence which then I compare between years for each period.

Comment: Yes: the ratio always has infinite expectation.  This is because the denominator has positive probability of being zero.  In other words, you are attempting to predict an undefined quantity.  I suspect you ought to be interested in a ratio of *rate parameters,* but that's only a guess.  If you could elaborate on what you are trying to do, we might be able to propose helpful approaches.

Comment: yep, my idea is that the ratio of the rate parameters have a distribution from which to extract the predicted ratio of event, and that this last one, thanks to bayesian regularization would put zero probability on impossible values. But maybe what I want doesn't exists.
In theory I'd be fine with just the rate parameters ratio (my backup solution), but I was bugged by the lower variance than the actual number of events.

Comment: added my specific case

Comment: I changed your title to reflect the question in the body, thereby solving @whuber: remark

Comment: But note that since process II seems to be a subset of process I, you can simply count x= number process II points, n=number process I points, and then x will be binomial

Comment: thanks, I added a clearer explanation. Actually the final output is the comparison between two incidences, so a rate ratio.

Comment: also, I realized that using a binomial model, or an offset on the total cases instead of the days would imply that the total is fixed and not itself uncertain, isn't it?

Comment: Working on two Poisson samples, a [recent paper by C. Graziani](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.12.07.20244954v1.full) suggests using a reparameterisation into ratio and total expectation to isolate the posterior on the ratio.